# clojure-contrib.jar import error

Tags: java, clojure, clojure-contrib

Command line is "D:\Progra~1\Java\jre6\bin\java.exe -jar D:\Old\Clojure\clojure.jar D:\Old\Clojure\clojure-contrib.jar"
Following error appears:
clojure.lang.Compiler$CompilerException: clojure-contrib.jar:0: Unable to resolve symbol: PK♥♦ in this context

clojure-contrib version is 1.1.0
How to invoke clojure with libraries right?

Comment: Where did the jars come from?  Did you download them or build them from source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try installing Clojure Box? It seems to be the prefered way to install Clojure in Windows according to http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Clojure_Programming/Getting_Started#Windows I've found the page very helpful when installing for other platforms.

Answer (score 1):

One thought is that you're passing two jars to -jar and not on the classpath. You probably want something like:

```
java.exe -cp d:\old\clojure-contrib.jar -jar d:\old\clojure.jar
```

I'd guess that your CLI invocation is causing clojure.jar to be launched by itself, and then clojure is trying to read in clojure-contrib.jar as an argument.